# Assigning multiple values to multiple variables in a single line

Tags: java, python, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write the Java equivalent of the following Python Inversion-Sort algorithm:

```
import numpy as np

def main(items):

    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and items[j] < items[j-1]:
            items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]
            j -= 1

    print(items)

main(np.array([4, 78, 23, 24, 56, 7, 9]))
```

This is the Java version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sorters {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Sorters sort = new Sorters();
        int[] items = {4, 78, 23, 24, 56, 7, 9};
        sort.insertionSort(items);
    }

    public void insertionSort(int[] items) {

        for(int i=1 ; i<items.length ; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while(j>0 && items[j] < items[j-1]) {
                items[j] = items[j-1]; // These two lines are
                items[j-1] = items[j]; // causing the error
                j -=1;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(items));
    } 
}
```

I've narrowed the issue down to the two lines that are commented as such, above (in the Java method).

If I give the Python function this array: `[4, 78, 23, 24, 56, 7, 9]` (for example), everything works fine. However, if I give the same array to the Java method, I get this in return: `[4, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78]`.

Could someone tell me how to write the Java equivalent of Python's `items[j], items[j-1] = items[j-1], items[j]`? Explanations welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Python is great in some aspects, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you need to use a `temp` variable to store one of the values when you swap between the items[j] with items[j-1]. It should be something like that:

```
int temp = items[j];
items[j] = items[j-1];
items[j-1] = temp;
```

What happens is that you lose the original value so each iteration of the loop you get to copy into items[j] the value of items[j-1].

That's how you got your output.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to swap the two indexes. You can do it like this

    `int tmp = items[j];
    items[j] = items[j-1];
    items[j-1] = tmp;`